# Make column heights equal to the smallest column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-multicolumn-layout

There a ton of answers on SO on how to make columns equal height based upon the content of the largest column, however I am looking to make all columns equal height based upon the *smallest* column.

[image]

In this example, I want all columns to have the same height as the middle column and the content within the two larger columns to scroll. I am using Bootstrap 4 but am open to any other solutions.

Comment: So the smallest column height can be variable, and you need to detect it then use that to set the other heights?

Comment: Yep that's correct!

Comment: Measure them all and set the height of the other ones? Same code as making match the max. Unsure what your question is. You ought to try something, then ask a question if it doesn't work including the code you tried and any error messages/unexpected behavior

Comment: where is your HTML, please follow the rules of [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use javascript.

1. Store all the column heights into an array.
2. Loop through and pick the smallest height.
3. Set the height of the other divs based on the smallest height.

```
// Get all the columns
const columns = document.querySelectorAll('.column');
// Array for storing height values for columns
var columnHeights= [];

// Add Column Heights to array
for(index=0; index<columns.length; index++) {
    column= columns[index];
    columnHeights.push(column.getBoundingClientRect().height);

}
// Get the minimum column height
Array.min = function(heightsArray){
    return Math.min.apply( Math, heightsArray );
};
var minimumHeight = Array.min(columnHeights);

// Set the height of the other columns based on the minimum height
columns.forEach(col => {
    col.style.height = minimumHeight+'px';
});
```

A working pen is [here](https://codepen.io/DarkNRhalKarl/pen/ydyMNr?editors=0010)

Comment: Why would you modify the Arrays object adding a min function? Answers should focus on the problem and avoid introducing unnecessary code.